# QML how to set color in a mouseArea

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, mousearea

I want to design the following button layout:

[image: Link]

It has a restart button image laid on top of a blue background. I want to replicate the same in Qt using QML. I am using a MouseArea Qt Quick object over which I am overlapping the image in *Stretch* fill mode. However there is no option to get a blue background for the mouse area. Currently it looks like this:

[image: Link]

The corresponding code for the same:

```
MouseArea {
    id: restartbutton
    x: 669
    width: 50
    height: 50
    opacity: 1
    antialiasing: false
    hoverEnabled: true
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 8
    z: 1

    Image {
        id: image2
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "restart_icon.png"
    }

}
```

How do I set the background for MouseArea here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `Rectangle` like this :

```
Rectangle {
  width:50
  height: 50
  Image {
    anchors.fill:parent
    source: "restart_icon.png"
  }
  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill:parent
    onClicked: {...}
  }
}
```

Take a look at the [QML Advanced Tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-advtutorial.html) for further informations

Comment: Hi! To improve this answer, you could *actually set the background color* in your example.

Comment: Also it might be better to have the `MouseArea` as the root-node (swap `Rectangle` with `MouseArea`) and then expose the `Rectangle`s `color` as a `property alias background: myRect.color`. The reason is, that the `MouseArea` has more signals and properties that might be relevant to expose, than the `Rectangle`. If you want to have a clean interface and expose only a minimum, a `Item` as root would be the alternative.

Comment: Yes this works. And like @derM said better to have MouseArea as root.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to read that way:

```
   MouseArea { id: clickArea
        anchors {
            fill: parent 
            margins: -10   // optional to enlarge the backgound / click zone
        }
        onClicked: {
            console.log("clicked!")
        }
        Rectangle {  // background, also allowing the click
            anchors.fill: clickArea
            border.color: "black"
            color: "lightblue"
            opacity: 0.3
        }
   }
```